# How to paste rendered html as markdown in sublime text?

Tags: markdown, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I used to use an app called Ulysses. It is a beautiful way to write in markdown. It has it's limitations so I managed to install few packages in sublime text and give it the same features Ulysses has. Now I can not find any package to do the following. I'll give a short scenario, as I can't explain it otherwise:

I am reading a blog post. I selected it all and hit copy. In Ulysses, I'd press `cmd+alt+v` it would ask me where is the content coming from, I'd select `from HTML`. The end result is the same content from the web, but formatted in markdown. For example, if the blog post has a subtitle with `h2` Ulysses would paste that as `## title`

I tried searching for a similar plugin in Sublime Text, I installed `ClipboardCommands` and `super-awesome-paste`. I can't recall what they did, but neither did what I needed. Does such a plugin exist?

Answer (score 7):

To search for Sublime Text plugins, use Package Control's [search](https://packagecontrol.io/search). A quick search for [`convert html markdown`](https://packagecontrol.io/search/convert%20html%20markdown) yields two relevant results: [`HTML2Text`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML2Text) and [`Pandoc`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pandoc). Both will convert HTML to Markdown. The `Pandoc` plugin requires [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org) on the system.

Comment: Thanks. None of them do what I described above

Comment: @relidon The description for HTML2Text is: *Converts files, selection and clipboard content from HTML to Text/Valid markdown using html2text* (which is a Python module). That sounds similar to what you described. Pandoc will convert a view, so you'd have to paste first. If you want to get **exactly** the same functionality as you had before, you'll either need to keep using your old program, or write your own plugin.

Comment: HTML2Text would do it, specifically the option "HTML2Text: Convert clipboard content". You could even bind a keyboard shortcut of your choice to invoke it.